# Use multi-modifier key combination in autohotkey to replace alt-tab

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> as a modifier, and then <kbd>d</kbd>, as a replacement for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key combination to switch windows in Windows.

I've tried the following script:

```
#^! & d::AltTab
```

But that won't work ("Error: invalid hotkey"), presumably because only one modifier is supposed to be used, which is also how the examples in the documentation are constructed.

**Is there a way to make this work nonetheless?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Alt-Tab Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#alttab) says

> Each Alt-Tab hotkey must be either a single key or a combination of
> two keys, which is typically achieved via the ampersand symbol (&).

[Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) says

> Combinations of three or more keys are not supported.

Try this:

```
#^!d::
    AltTabMenu := true  ; assign the boolean value "true" or 1 to this variable
    Send {Alt Down}{Tab}
return

#If (AltTabMenu)       ; If this variable has the value "true"

    ~*Alt Up::         ; release the Alt Key to
        Send {Alt Up}  ; close the menu
        AltTabMenu := false ; Set the variable to false in preparation for the next press of the #^!d hotkey.
    return

#If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; unfortunately, it is not working. A slight adjustment, that seems totally pointless, did work. I'll post it as an answer here, as I can't cram it into this comment :)

Comment: Works fine here. Try it first of all as a stand-alone script: Use only this code in the script and close all other scripts that may interfere. If it works you can add it in another (main-)script but in a proper position (e.g. before other #If(Win) directives because the #^!d hotkey won't work universally within such a directive).

Answer (score 0):

@user3419297's suggestion was not working for me:

```
AltTabMenu := false

#^!d::
    AltTabMenu := true
    Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}
return

#If (AltTabMenu)       
    ~*Alt Up::          
        Send, {Alt Up}  
        AltTabMenu := false 
    return

#If
```

...but this seemingly (to me at least) functionally identical code *is* working:

```
AltTabMenu := false

#If not (AltTabMenu)
    #^!d::
        AltTabMenu := true  
        Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}
    return

#If (AltTabMenu)        
    #^!d:: Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}
    ~*Alt Up::          
        Send, {Alt Up}  
        AltTabMenu := false
    return

#If
```

---

**edit: I've added the shifted variant as well to select the *previous* window**

```
AltTabMenu := false

#If not (AltTabMenu)
    #^!d::
        AltTabMenu := true  
        Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}
    return

#If (AltTabMenu)        
    #^+!d:: Send, {Alt Down}{Left}
    #^!d:: Send, {Alt Down}{Right}
    ~*Alt Up::          
        Send, {Alt Up}  
        AltTabMenu := false
    return

#If
```